# Python return statement in a function

Tags: python

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    for letter in a_str:
        if letter in "aeiou":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    print("Done!")
```

Hi, I have a function above that is not returning True when I do

```
print(has_a_vowel("happy")
```

I know it is because it only checks the first character and the return False statement is executed which terminates the code. However, I do not know how to position the return statements to make it such that as long as there is a vowel in the string, it will return True.

Comment: Don’t return false inside the for loop

Comment: Hi Mark! I tried but the function returned None if I tried the string "mnkrty"
I want it to return False if there is no vowel, and True if there is a vowel.

Comment: Put the `return False` *outside of the loop*, where you currently have the (unreachable) `print("Done!")`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Simply because it’s a beginner question?

Answer (score 1):

Does this make sense?

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    print("Starting...")
    for letter in a_str:
        print("Checking", letter)
        if letter in "aeiou":
            print(letter, "is a vowel, returning True")
            return True
        else:
            print(letter, "is not a vowel")
    return False # If it gets here without returning True it is False.
```

Comment: YES IT DOES! It works like a charm now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you just need to return at the end of the function because you need to search in the whole string if have a vowel, so that will return true, otherwise at the end of function will return false.

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    print("Starting...")
    for letter in a_str:
        print("Checking", letter)
        if letter in "aeiou":
            print(letter, "is a vowel, returning True")
            return True
    return False
    print("Done!")
    
print(has_a_vowel("happy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm never checks any further than the first letter because you return either way. The function can return as soon as a vowel is found but if it is not a vowel you need to keep searching. Try moving the `return False` statement to the end of the function (after printing "Done!").

Answer (score 0):

**Some other ways to check it:**

**1.**

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    if any([letter in 'aeiou' for letter in a_str]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(has_a_vowel("happy"))
```

**Result:**

```
True
```

**2.**

```
def has_a_vowel(a_str):
    print('Starting...')
    for letter in a_str:
        print()
        print ('Checking', letter)
        if letter in 'aeiou':
            print (letter, 'is a vowel, returning True')
            yield True
        else:
            print (letter, 'is not a vowel, returning False')
            yield False
    print('Done!')

for result in has_a_vowel("happy"):
    print(result)
```

**Result:**

```
Starting...

Checking h h is not a vowel, returning False False

Checking a a is a vowel, returning True True

Checking p p is not a vowel, returning False False

Checking p p is not a vowel, returning False False

Checking y y is not a vowel, returning False False 
Done!
```